# How can I make drag and drop with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

how can I make the exact same thing using jquery?

```
   function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  }

function drag(ev) {
 ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
 }

function drop(ev) {

  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  if ( event.target.nodeName !== "IMG" ) {
  event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
   }
  if(document.getElementById(data).getAttribute('id')=='drag0' && 
  ev.target.id=='c0')
 d0=true;
 else 
 if (document.getElementById(data).getAttribute('id')=='drag0')
 d0=false;
  if(document.getElementById(data).getAttribute('id')=='drag1' && 
  ev.target.id=='c1')
   d1=true;
  else
  if(document.getElementById(data).getAttribute('id')=='drag1')
   d1=false;

  if (d0==true && d1=true)
  {alert("congrats!");
   window.location.reload();
   }
    }
```

I tried to make the if statements like this but I don't now how should I put them in a function and where to use that function after

```
if($("#data")=='drag0' && ev.target.id=='c0')
 d0=true;
 else
  if ($("#data")=='drag0')
 d0=false;
    if($("#data")=='drag1' && ev.target.id=='c1')
  d1=true;
  else
  if($("#data")=='drag1')
   d1=false;
```

I use it in HTML like that:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td id="c0" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">

            </td>
            <td id="c1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          </td>
            <td id="c2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
            </td>
       </tr>
         </table>

        var imgStr = '<img class="'+img+'" src="bo.png"'+'" alt = "" 
        draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" 
        id="drag'+num+'">'+'<br>';
       document.write(imgStr); 
       document.close();
```